# Expectation of the product of values on the four lateral sides of a die

Tags: probability

The numbers on a standard six-sided die are arranged such that numbers on opposite faces always add to 7.The die is rolled, and the product of the numbers on the four lateral faces of the die is calculated (ignoring the numbers on the top and bottom).What is the expected value of the product?

My reasoning in this exercise is to calculate all the possible equiprobable cases which at the end are just 3 ( putting numbers on the top and bottom) and then calculating the expectation :

$$E[x]=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)*2*3*4*5+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)*1*3*4*6+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)*1*2*5*6 = 84 $$

Is this just right?I was wondering if there's any alternate method using expectation of the product of indipendent variables but here doesn't apply right?

Comment: Your approach is correct. Linearity of expectation applies to sums, not to products (so it's not a surprise that it doesn't work).

Comment: Looks fine. Linearity of expectation is very often useful in sums and in combination with symmetry. Symmetry lacks here.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers!

Comment: Anyway I was thinking to another thing ahah namely expectation of product of indipendent variables...but here it doesn't apply right?

Comment: No, I don't see a reason nor a way to apply that here.